# Is the space of smooth maps $C^{\infty}(M,N)$ with the Whitney $C^{\infty}$ topology locally compact, if $M$ is compact

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, gt.geometric-topology, gn.general-topology, differential-topology

The title says it all:

Let $M$ be a compact manifold and $N$ a (possible non compact) manifold. Equip the space of smooth functions $C^{\infty}(M,N)$ with the Whitney $C^{\infty}$ topology. (The strong an the weak one coincide, since $M$ is compact)

Hirsch's book on differential topology states without proof that this space is completely metrizable, second countable and locally contractible.

However, is it locally compact?

Comment: Take $N = \mathbb{R}$. Then a locally compact Hausdorff topological vector space is necessarily finite-dimensional (https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/locally-compact-topological-vector-spaces/).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M,\mathbb{R})$ is not a topological vector space. The maximal topological vector space inside is $\mathcal{C}_c^\infty(M,\mathbb{R})$

Answer (score 3):

No. Look at [this book](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/manifolds_of_differentiable_mappings.pdf)
or [this other book](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/apbookh-ams.pdf) for much more information.